# XSL copy-of with removing specific attribute and tag in all hierarchy

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove one specific attribute (d) of all specific tag (qq) while copying with xsl. Is it possible to do this with xsl:copy-of (not xsl:copy)?

XML source:

```
<main>
    <x b="c">
      <y b="e">
        <qq d="f"/>
      </y>
      <z>
        <qq d="f"/>
        <y b="e">
          <qq d="f"/>
        </y>
      </z>
      <qq d="g"/>
    </x>
</main>
```

Wanted output:

```
<x b="c">
  <y b="e">
    <qq />
  </y>
  <z>
    <qq />
    <y b="e">
      <qq />
    </y>
  </z>
  <qq />
</x>
```

I tried

```
<xsl:copy-of select="x[name(.) !='qq' and name(@) != 'd'"/>
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Using `copy-of` is not the right way to go about this because it copies everything for the selected node along with descendant nodes. What does the rest of your XSL look like?

Answer (score 2):

`copy-of` won't help you here, but an identity template will:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="qq/@d" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result when run on your sample input:

```
<x b="c">
  <y b="e">
    <qq />
  </y>
  <z>
    <qq />
    <y b="e">
      <qq />
    </y>
  </z>
  <qq />
</x>
```